# Saltstack Halite Error! Failed to run command:

Tags: amazon-ec2, salt-stack

I have a salt master server set up, and currently I'm testing with two minions attached. I am able to run states and salt module commands from the salt master machine directly with no issues.

I installed and set up halite per the documentation. I'm logged in as a user and am able to see the minions in the list without issue, however any command that I attempt to run using the halite web ui fails.

Here are the pam and halite sections from my master config:

```
external_auth:
  pam:
    ubuntu:
      - grains.*
      - status.*
      - sys.*
      - test.*
      - cp_bakfile.*
      - ipt_config.*
      - '@runner'
      - '@wheel'
    adam:
      - .*
      - '@runner'
      - '@wheel'
    cfadmin:
      - .*
      - '@runner'
      - '@wheel'

halite:
  level: 'debug'
  server: 'cherrypy'
  host: '0.0.0.0'
  port: '8080'
  cors: False
  tls: False
  certpath: '/etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt'
  keypath: '/etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.key'
  pempath: '/etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.pem'
```

I'm logged in as the user Adam when I try to run the command:

supervisord.restart all on my minion.

The error is as follows:

Error! Failed to run command: supervisord.restart on target: myminion

Anyone have any idea what I should check or what I may have done wrong?

The master is on Amazon EC2, ubuntu 14.04, as are the minions.

[image: issue screenshot]

Comment: It looks like halite isn't giving you a specific error.  What do you get when you run the same class/method from the cli?

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but in case anyone else comes across this question, the halite project has been deprecated and is no longer developed.

https://github.com/saltstack/halite